# Displaying a dynamic list of names in a tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code snippet in a gridview:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label
    ID="lblRecipientsCount"
    runat="server"
    Text='<%#String.Join(",",((Share.Service.Message)Container.DataItem).Recipients.Count()) %>'
    ToolTip='<%#String.Join(","((Share.Service.Message)Container.DataItem).Recipients.ToString()) %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The data-bind tag that counts recipients works fine. When I add the second binding tag to the tool tip, the tool tip displays Share.Service.Person[].

My ultimate goal is for the tool tip to display a comma separated list of recipient names.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var message = (Share.Service.Message)e.Row.DataItem;
        var lblRecipientsCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRecipientsCount");
        lblRecipientsCount.Text = message.Recipients.Count();
        lblRecipientsCount.ToolTip = string.Join(",", message.Recipients.Select(rec => rec.Name));
    }
}
```

Databinding expressions don't support complex lambda expression(afaik).

Codebehind is also more readable, maintainable and less error-prone.

Comment: On Count, I'm getting: The property 'System.Array.Count' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible.

Comment: @Rex_C: Then use `Length` or `Count()` if it's an array (edited).

Comment: Now its throwing an error on the Select now, and it can't resolve my .Name property.

Comment: @Rex_C: Then you need to show your `Share.Service.Message` and the `Recipient` class. Is the property `Name` at all?